# Problema con Arreglo genérico

Tags: java

Necesito ordenar un grupo de empleados por nombres, pero no sé cómo hacerlo, ya tengo implementado el `compareTO`.

```
public class Arreglo< T extends Comparable<T> > {
    T[] arreglo;
    int cantidad;



public Arreglo(int max){
    arreglo = (T[])new Comparable[max];
    cantidad = 0;
}

public void adicionar(T elemento){
    arreglo[cantidad++] = elemento;
}

public int buscar(T x){
    for(int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++){
        if(x.equals(arreglo[i])){
            return i;
        }
    } 

    return -1;
}

public T minimo(){
    T menor = arreglo[0];
    for(T e : arreglo){
        if(e != null && menor.compareTo(e) < 0){
            menor = e;
        } 
    }
    return menor;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para tu pregunta he realizado un ejemplo el cual es de la siguiente manera:

Tengo la clase Empleados de la siguiente manera para desarrollar el ejemplo

```js
package stackoverflow;

public class Empleados implements Comparable<Empleados> {

 private String nombre;
 private String apellido;
 private int documento;


 public String getNombre() {
  return nombre;
 }
 public void setNombre(String nombre) {
  this.nombre = nombre;
 }
 public String getApellido() {
  return apellido;
 }
 public void setApellido(String apellido) {
  this.apellido = apellido;
 }
 public int getDocumento() {
  return documento;
 }
 public void setDocumento(int documento) {
  this.documento = documento;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "Empleados [nombre=" + nombre + ", apellido=" + apellido + ", documento=" + documento + "]";
 }

 @Override
 public int compareTo(Empleados o) {
  return this.nombre.compareTo(o.nombre);
 }
}
```

**Clase de ejecución, para la prueba del ejemplo**

```js
package stackoverflow;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class StackOverFlow {

 private static String datos = "[{\"nombre\":\"Pepito\",\"apellido\":\"Perez\",\"documento\":12345},{\"nombre\":\"Ana elisa\",\"apellido\":\"Torres\",\"documento\":123456},{\"nombre\":\"Luis Alberto\",\"apellido\":\"Carreto\",\"documento\":1234567},{\"nombre\":\"Ruth\",\"apellido\":\"Robles\",\"documento\":12345678}]";

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  Type type = new TypeToken<List<Empleados>>() {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  }.getType();

  // Armo una lista de empleados
  List<Empleados> lEmpleados = new Gson().fromJson(datos, type);

  // Imprimo la lista en el orden inicial
  System.out.println(lEmpleados.toString());

  // Ordenamos la lista
  Collections.sort(lEmpleados);

  // Imprimimos la lista ordenada
  System.out.println(lEmpleados.toString());
 }

}
```